# how to create a flyout panel in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2013

As the question suggests, I'd like to know if it's possible to add a flyout panel to a regular wpf application, specifically to a UserControl. From the results I've got from googling, most available flyouts seem to come packaged with a template of some sort without explaining how they're made.

The closest I've got is the Extended WPF Toolkit but even that has no documentation on how to use it. As it is I'm currently trying to keep to the MVVM pattern. So is there anyone with an idea of how to make one?

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of a "Flyout Panel"? i.e. how does such an animal look like?

Comment: I think you need an Adorner Layer, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms743737%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: You try http://mahapps.com/controls/flyouts.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add flyouts using [mahapps.metro](http://mahapps.com/), which is free and opensource.

Comment: Well I added it's libraries and implemented it the xaml. It works. Thanks.